# Change ItemType from file to directory

Tags: windows, file, powershell, directory

to clean up my hard disk I use a Powershell script that automatically copies video files from one folder to a different hard disk and deletes them from the old folder.
Now I installed a new hard disk and wanted to use it to save the files. I changed the paths in the script, but unfortunately forgot to create the destination folder on the new hard disk. The files should be copied to the folder *Y:\Moved*. However, since this did not exist, the script created a file called *"Moved"*.

Is it possible to convert this file so that Windows recognizes it as a folder? So to change the **ItemType** from *"file"* to *"directory"*?

Best regards,
Florian

Comment: Put your script here

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse -Include "*.mkv"| Move-Item -Destination $target -Force -Confirm:$false`

Answer (score 0):

No, changing a file to a folder is not possible. Rename the file you created, create the folder, then move the renamed file to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake in thinking. I assumed that a single file was created from all files (just like a folder). Of course, this is not the case. The *Moved* file was overwritten for each video. So the file only holds the last video. Thanks for your answers anyway.